# Asp.net Core Identity - Azure Authentication Middleware

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, middleware

Is there a package for authenticating with Azure AD, for Asp.net Core?

For example, the following Authentication packages exist, when querying Nuget:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount

I tried to use the MicrosoftAccount package, but after wiring it up successfully, I got the following error from the Microsoft page:

```
Application '{my-app-id}' {my-app-name} is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint.
```

There's [examples](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/) that don't use a middleware package, but the middleware package offers ease of use, and more directly integrates with the Identity framework.

Are there any direct packages that use Azure AD, or anyway to specify that the MicrosoftAccount package should point to the organizations/azure/tenant url?

Comment: Did you try https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
authBuilder
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(Auth.Constants.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = clientId;
        options.ClientId = clientSecret;
        if (tenantId != null)
        {
            var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/authorize?resource={resource}";
            options.TokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token?resource={resource}";
        }
    });
```

- `tenantId` - look at the "Endpoints" section from the "App registrations" blade. You can extract it from the URLs, or use those URLs directly instead of what I've done above.
- `clientId` - this is your "Application ID" in your registered app.
- `clientSecret` - this is a password you create and register under the "Keys" section of your registered app.

You can then get back more information by using the access token with https://graph.microsoft.com, such as adding options like the following:

```
options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim(ClaimTypes.Name);
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "displayName");
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "userPrincipalName");
options.Events = new OAuthEvents
{
    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
    {
        // Get the GitHub user
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var user = JObject.Parse(contents);

        context.RunClaimActions(user);
    }
};
```